# how Sets and Relations are useful and related to logic programming?

Tags: logic-programming

i am getting started with logic programming, but i am forced to do contents of discrete mathematics first. but i don't see the relation here.
Sets however is used in predicate logic but Relations, how are they related to logic programming.

Answer (score 0):

Relations are used to look at how one set is either related to itself or another set and this can be used quite a lot in programming.

for example the cartesian product:
set of pairs (x,y) such that xeA and yeB
A = {a1, a2} B = {b1, b2, b3}

AxB (A cross B) = {(A1,B1), (A1,B2), ... }

you can use relations to  find the relation between two elements of the same set, for example:

A = {1,2,3,4,5}   x,y e A xRy iff x